# Submitting Forms from Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of items which is dynamically updated via an ajax call whenever a new item is added. There's a comment form included in each of these list items that has a comment field and a hidden field which indicates which item has been commented on.

I'm using the jquery form plugin to submit these forms using ajax. The problem I keep running into is that the forms are not recognized by the plugin so they run normally (posting and redirecting to ajax/comment.php). After doing some digging I think this is because the forms are being loaded dynamically and the script can't 'see' them. I've read about eval() being a possible solution to get the script to run correctly. Right now the code executes correctly if I don't use ajax to populate the page.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = {  
    url: 'ajax/comment.php',
}; 
$('.commentsubmit').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

    return false; 
}); 
}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the forms are loaded dynamically, change `.submit` to this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.commentsubmit', function () {
```

This will delegate the `submit` event to any `.commentsubmit` forms that may not be added to the DOM at the time you call `.on`.

On an unrelated note, use `e.preventDefault()`, not `return false`: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: It's still redirecting to ajax/comment.php

Comment: What you wrote worked. It's running the ajax form and redirecting which it wasn't doing before. So the function is finally running, but it is still redirecting

Comment: I changed it back to return false; and it is working correctly. Thanks

Comment: @centree sorry, I should have specified that you  need to pass `e` to the callback, as in (`function (e) {`)